# 18.10 Chrome browser Kindle Cloud Reader won't load books

Tags: google-chrome

With my chrome browser in Windows 10 I can view my Kindle books in the Kindle Cloud Reader.

In Ubuntu 18.10 with the same browser, settings synced, books are not displayed in either of the tabs ('Cloud' and 'Downloaded'). I see only the spinning disk.

The security settings block popups and forwards, but I have exceptions for amazon sites.

Comment: I disabled the extensions "AdBlockPlus" and "Dark Reader" and it worked.